# why the object literal doesn't have a length property throws error

Tags: javascript

I have a simple object as below

```js
{"a" : 1}.length
```

This throws an error and makes sense that the object doesn't have a length property in its prototype ... but

why does assigning it a variable and accessing the props which are not there will return `undefined` ?

```js
const obj = {"a" : 123};

console.log(obj.length)
```

sorry, what am I missing here , thanks for your suggestions ..

Comment: If you reference a property that does not exist, the result is `undefined`. That's the way JavaScript works.

Comment: The first piece of code returns that error for a reason completely unrelated to the reference to `.length`.

Comment: `console.log({"a" : 1}.length)` ?

Comment: @Pointy yep true that ... thanks for the references, will have a look :)

Comment: Amazing, the links were totally helpful .... so it treats as the block in that context  idkjs yet 

Comment: To make your first more equivalent to the second, your maybe after `({"a" : 1}).length`  otherwise the first is a syntax error, rather than a logical one.   Remember `{` is also used for block scope `{ somecodeHere(); }` as well as object literals.

Comment: yeah @Keith ... not sure how I missed that though :|